# Why isn't Eclipse-IDE console showing 'Pass: 2' in TestNG test output?

Tags: console, output, testng-eclipse

In my Eclipse-IDE console, after executing TestNG test, why I am not getting 'Pass: 2' result in below line in console.

Total tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Skips: 1

## Here is my output in console

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
This is test method 1....
This is test method 2....
This is test method 3....
This is test method 4....
This is test method 5....

## ===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Skips: 1

I am running my TestNG test, the console should show like 'Pass: 2' in the last line in output in console.
It has to show that in that line.